# MAUI-Sqlite-System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms

Tags: maui

I am getting below Exception when I try to read or write data to local DB on my MAUI application.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
> File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
> at MyApp.SqlHelper.GetConnection() in /Users/MyCompany/Projects/MyProject-maui/MyProject/Renderers/SqlHelper.cs:line 28
> at MyApp.SqlHelper..ctor() in /Users/MyCompany/Projects/MyProject-maui/MyProject/Renderers/SqlHelper.cs:line 18
> at MyProject.App.get_Database() in /Users/MyCompany/Projects/MyProject-maui/MyProject/App.xaml.cs:line 92

I have installed below packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLiteNetExtensions.Async" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.6" />
```

**My Code:**

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public static SqlHelper Database
{
    get
    {
        if (database == null)
        {
            database = new SqlHelper();
        }
        return database;
    }
}
```

**SqlHelper.cs**

```
public SqlHelper()
{
    database = GetConnection();//Exception is on this line
    database.CreateTable<Favorites>();
}
```

It is working fine on Android platform and issue is only on iOS platform.

**Update**

```
public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    SQLiteConnection sqlitConnection;
    var sqliteFilename = "Favorites.db3";
    IFolder folder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    string path = PortablePath.Combine(folder.Path.ToString(), sqliteFilename);
    sqlitConnection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
    return sqlitConnection;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code about ```GetConnection()```? Or share a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT GetConnection code added.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in GetConnection method to see which line cause this error?

Comment: Did you use PCLStorage, which is not compatible with .net7- ios?

Comment: You could try using [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android). SImply use ```string path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory,sqliteFilename);```

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I am using `PCLStorage`, I tried the above code and getting below error: Error CS1061 'IFileSystem' does not contain a definition for 'AppDataDirectory' and no accessible extension method 'AppDataDirectory' accepting a first argument of type 'IFileSystem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try replacing ```FileSystem``` with  ```Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FileSystem```.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Please post it as your answer. I have also commented the `IFolder folder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;`, on that line the exception was throwing.

Comment: I have already added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error thrown in the following line was caused by PCLStorage NuGet, which is not compatible with .NET7-iOS.

```
IFolder folder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
```

So as an alternative, you could use [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android).

You may try the following code,

```
using FileSystem = Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FileSystem;

.....

    public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SQLiteConnection sqlitConnection;
        var sqliteFilename = "Favorites.db3";
        
        string path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory,sqliteFilename);
        sqlitConnection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
        return sqlitConnection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0)?
Their code specifies a database path and this should usually work.

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string DatabaseFilename = "TodoSQLite.db3";

    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
         // open the database in read/write mode
         SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
         // create the database if it doesn't exist
         SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
         // enable multi-threaded database access
         SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

    public static string DatabasePath => Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);
}


SQLiteAsyncConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<Favorites>();
```

Comment: I have added the GetConnection codes to the question, Is the above code I need to add there for creating table?

Comment: You are using a different file path: FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage instead, FileSystem.AppDataDirectory. Your app probably doesnt have permission to write in this directoy.